# ADAL V3, Azure Data Lake, Certificates and ServiceClientCredentials

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, adal, azure-data-lake, azure-eventhub

I am in a bit of a jam, I need to access Azure Event Hub and Azure Data Lake from the same service principal in the same piece of code (C#). The service principal is an Azure AD application and I am authenticating with a certificate.

If I use ADAL 2.x and authenticate I can connect to Azure Data Lake fine, but Event Hubs (WindowsAzure.ServiceBus) is not able to authenticate (see further down).

The ADAL 2.x code I use for creating the credential for Azure Data Lake is as below, this works 100% fine:

```
  public static ServiceClientCredentials GetCreds_SPI_Cert(string tenant, Uri tokenAudience, string clientId, string certificateThumbprint)
        {
            var certificate = FindCertificateByThumbprint(certificateThumbprint);

            SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new SynchronizationContext());

            var clientAssertionCertificate = new ClientAssertionCertificate(clientId, certificate);
            var serviceSettings = ActiveDirectoryServiceSettings.Azure;
            serviceSettings.TokenAudience = tokenAudience;

            var creds = ApplicationTokenProvider.LoginSilentWithCertificateAsync(tenant, clientAssertionCertificate, serviceSettings).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            return creds;
        }
```

If I upgrade to ADAL v3 in order to gain access the Event Hub (WindowsAzure.ServiceBus requires it), then the following code works fine (for event hub):

```
public static TokenProvider GetTokenProviderViaCetificate(string tenant, Uri tokenAudience, string clientId, string certificateThumbprint)
{
    var certificate = FindCertificateByThumbprint(certificateThumbprint);
    return TokenProvider.CreateAadTokenProvider(
        new AuthenticationContext($"https://login.windows.net/{tenant}"),
        new ClientAssertionCertificate(clientId, certificate),
        ServiceAudience.EventHubsAudience);
}
```

Note that the token provider in the Event Hub authentication `CreateAadTokenProvider` is only available in ADALv3. The Service Bus and Data Lake clients also both require different types of credential.

If I use ADAL V3 and go back to the Data Lake code, the `GetCreds_SPI_Cert` fails with the following error:

> Method not found:
>   'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(System.String,
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.ClientAssertionCertificate)'.

In short, how do I use ADAL v3 to authenticate an Azure AD App service principal against Azure Data Lake (using a certificate)? I can't downgrade to ADAL 2.x due to the Event Hub dependency.

Comment: I'm trying to rack my brain, pretty sure I came across an adaptor to go between multiple versions of the ADAL, it was a while ago unfortunately my memory is a little fuzzy of it.

Comment: @AlexKeySmith, any clue would help, although apart sideloading separate app domains or shelling to some sort of CLI I don't see any reasonable options.

Comment: I'll try to remember to dig through my OneNote when back in the office tomorrow, it was for a slightly different problem but sounds related.

Comment: This might offer some hints, albeit probably not the answer directly: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/3f736b5af3851ab99bbaa98483ae537de0d48cfb/Documentation/AuthConflictsBetweenSDKs.md

Comment: If it proves useful let me know and I'll pop it as an answer.

Comment: That looks very promising - you legend. Pop it up as an answer and I will upvote + accept.

Comment: Jolly good show!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something that could aid devise a solution, albeit perhaps not the solution directly, is an authentication adapter documented deep in the github repo:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/3f736b5af3851ab99bbaa98483ae537de0d48cfb/Documentation/AuthConflictsBetweenSDKs.md

> Authentication conflicts can happen due to mixing old SDKs* and new
>   SDKs*. SDKs that depend on The credential types created by the new
>   authentication library
>   (Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.Azure.Authentication, type =
>   ServiceClientCredentials) are incompatible with the credential types
>   used in older SDKs (Microsoft.Azure.Common, type =
>   SubscriptionCloudCredentials). The problem is that using two different
>   authentication libraries will require you to authenticate twice, which
>   is a painful experience.

```
public class SubscriptionCredentialsAdapter : SubscriptionCloudCredentials
{
    ServiceClientCredentials _credentials;
    string _subscriptionId;

    public SubscriptionCredentialsAdapter(ServiceClientCredentials wrapped, string subscriptionId)
    {
        _credentials = wrapped;
        _subscriptionId = subscriptionId;
    }

    public override string SubscriptionId
    {
        get { return _subscriptionId; }
    }

    public override Task ProcessHttpRequestAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
       return _credentials.ProcessHttpRequestAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```